# if (Model.Objectives != null || Model.Objectives.ToString() =="<br/>") asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html, model

my application is MVC 3, I am hiding div by checking if the value in my database table is null.  I am using an InnovaHtmlEditor to enter data, when I delete the text, the InnovaHtmlEditor leaves `<br/>` in the table.  How can I check if there is only `<br/>`?

I tried:

```
(Model.Objectives != null || Model.Objectives.ToString() =="<br/>")
```

Comment: what is the problem with your solution?

Comment: Does not work!! I think  "<br/>" is wrong.

Comment: Did you try to remove any blank spaces in your Model.Objectives first?

Comment: Did not, how can I do that.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your original statement seems wrong:

```
// if objectives is not null OR it is not null and is equal to <br/>
(Model.Objectives != null || Model.Objectives.ToString() =="<br/>")
```

You don't need to `Model.Objectives = "<br/>"`, it will never be called anyways because `"<br/>" != null`

```
// if objectives is not null
(Model.Objectives != null)
```

I would assume you want something like this:

```
// if objectives isn't null AND it is not <br/>
(Model.Objectives != null && Model.Objectives.ToString() =="<br/>")
```

or

```
// if objectives is null OR objectives is <br/>
(Model.Objectives == null || Model.Objectives.ToString() =="<br/>")
```

Comment: Thanks Armen, || should be && I used the wrong logic. However, if there is more text than <br/> the div still hidden.  I just need to check if the only text in the string equals <br/>

Answer (score 0):

I am having **different solution** for your scenario.

That is, **when you clear the content** from text box you **send null to your database** table column.

Then you just need to check like below.It is very simple and elegant.

```
if (Model.Objectives == null)
{
   //Hide your div
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sampath, I agree but this will requires considerable coding because I have several tables and cells.  All what I need to find is how to check if a cell has just <br /> in it.  Thanks

Comment: OK sure.After finishing your task put that as answer.Good luck.